# PHP file extensions not affecting page

Tags: php, apache, ubuntu-16.04, file-extension

Whenever I go to any page of my website by typing in the url with the PHP file extension I am immediately redirected to the homepage of the website.
Example: https://websitename.com/folder/file.php
would redirect to just https://websitename.com

When I click on links to other pages within the website they go to the correct page, but the PHP file extension is still not shown. For example, all I see would be https://websitename.com

How can I make the website immediately direct to the correct page if the file extension is typed into the address bar. I'm using apache2 web server on ubuntu 16.04

Note: I did not attempt to configure my server to hide the file extension. I have no problem if it is revealed, but at the moment it isn't.

Comment: what' inside file.php

Comment: Its the respective webpage of the site. My site has multiple pages written with PHP and html.

Comment: is there an .htaccess file in your web root?

Comment: Yes, I have a few different .htaccess files for multiple folders

Comment: I already figured out what the problem was, as you can see in the answer I left, but thank you for your response anyways.

Answer (score 0):

It was a problem with how I setup the nameservers for my .tk domain name from Freenom. Sorry for wasting your time.